# Local non-mavenised SWC

Tags: maven, flash, maven-3, swc, flexmojos

I'm working on a project that requires a very complex maven build.

One swc we use is just for native Flash assets. All our assets are versioned separately in another git repo so I just want maven to include it as a local lib.

Until now we have been continuously uploading the swc to artifactory with each change and versioning it there. As all assets are versioned separately anyway this is a superphlues and arbitrary system.

I would just like to have it in a local 'lib' folder and not be versioned through maven. And I don't want to have to install to the .m2 folder either as this will not automatically pick up changes to the local file as far as I know. I just want the swc to be treated as the code is.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what stops you from *just have it in a local folder* ?

Comment: Maven ignores local swcs

Comment: you can define a source folder but not a lib folder

Comment: I have to admit that I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. First of all you could deploy snapshot versions of your resource and have that updated on every build (Using Maved "-U" switch) ... that should resove the manual updating ... Another option would eventually be to use Mavens "system" scope and provide an absolute path to the other SWC (Haven't tested that though)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I realise I never came back to this.

I eventually decided I was trying to do something that was not an intended use case.

In the end we just absorbed the code into the main project.